# why phpmyadmin didn't work?

Tags: installation, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

When run phpmyadmin it is not working and i get this message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

How it's not found in case of I'm just setting up from few minutes. 
And i just use the commands in this link  http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

**without this comand**

`mysql -u root`

and

`mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');`

**because i get this error**

```
ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using 
password: NO)
```

*and i don't know about that command
because it's first deal with ubuntu*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were trying to access phpmyadmin via `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` it usually isn't automatically installed.

You have to append an include to phpmyadmin conf file in the apache.conf file like so:

```
echo "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Also, there shouldn't be a need to execute mysql commands to access your phpmyadmin. The ubuntu aptitude installer creates all the necessary database tables needed to get phpmyadmin up and running.

Also, Ubuntu provides some [great documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin) on how to get phpmyadmin running as well from either a package or if you want the latest upstream version you can manually install it as well.

Comment: it's frist time yo deal with linux and i don't know how to run php code in it i can't get used in easly can you tell me what i should do step by step

Comment: See the great documentation link i provided you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin

Comment: it's not working i get this error:  Include: command not found